# Нужно убрать Warning компоновки, куда и как в CMakeLists.txt записать /NO DEFAULTLIB:library?

Tags: cmake

CMakeLists.txt такой :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(VulkanTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
  set(
    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
    "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /JMC"
  )
else()
  set(
    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
    "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-implicit-fallthrough"
  )
endif()

file(GLOB sources
  *.cpp
  *.h
*.c
)

add_executable(
  VulkanTest
  ${sources} 
)

set(includes 
"D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/Libraries/glfw-3.3.7.bin.WIN64/include"
"C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.216.0/Include"
"D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/Libraries/glm"
)

include_directories(${includes})

target_link_libraries(VulkanTest "C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.216.0/Lib/vulkan-1.lib" )

target_link_libraries(VulkanTest "D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/Libraries/glfw-3.3.7.bin.WIN64/lib-vc2022/glfw3.lib")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /NODEFAULTLIB")
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786690/cmake-for-def-and-nodefaultlib

или так

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(target PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/NODEFAULTLIB:\"libname\"")
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно но что-то с этим вообще не собирается , одни ошибки main.obj : error LNK2019:

Comment: а со вторым вариантом

Comment: а что тут \"libname\" и почему кавычки экранируются?, что то непойму как

Comment: ну впишите ваше library

Comment: `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(VulkanTest PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/NODEFAULTLIB:\"MSVCRT\"") `
Вроде так у вас

Comment: ура! без варнингов ) спасибо
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(VulkanTest PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/NODEFAULTLIB:\"MSVCRT\"")

target_link_libraries(VulkanTest "C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.216.0/Lib/vulkan-1.lib" )

target_link_libraries(VulkanTest "D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/Libraries/glfw-3.3.7.bin.WIN64/lib-vc2022/glfw3.lib")